# What is an effective way to call a method based on all cases in a switch statement, but not for the default?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to change the text in a **TextView** I am about to display, but if the input does not match any of the cases, I do not want to call the method.

How can I write this in as few lines of code as possible?

```
switch (integer) {        
  case 1:
  case 2:
    replyOne.setText("string 1 & 2");
    break;
  case 3:
    replyOne.setText("string 3");
    break;
  default:
    Toast.makeText(this, "incorrect typing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

makeContactMessage(replyOne, messagesLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of **fewer lines of code**, just simply use if/else statements instead as follows:

```
if (integer == 1 || integer == 2) {
    replyOne.setText("string 1 & 2");
} else if (integer == 3) {
    replyOne.setText("string 3");
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "incorrect typing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Keep things simple; no need to overcomplicate things :-)

Comment: @rollback I agree, but how else would you write his code snippet with fewer lines of code?

Comment: Why do you want fewer lines of code so much? No one counts the lines! Readability > lines of code

Comment: sorry, I thought fewer lines would correlate to readability. Hades' answer gave me insight into one of my problems: I was calling setText() multiple times.

Comment: @rollback I also value readability more! It's just that the OP's code snippet doesn't seem to get any shorter than that in terms of lines of code, hence why I suggested this!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! However, I'm still not sure how to not setText() for the default case.

Answer (score 0):

Put the String logic in your Model and set the Textview only once. Your presenter should not have any logic.

```
String reply = model.getReply();
replyOne.setText(reply)
```

---

```
//in your model,
String getReply(){
  switch(){
  }
  return ...
}
```

Comment: How does this fix my issue with not wanting to call a method for the default case? Also, what do you mean by presenter and model?

Comment: @EthanWatson return null if there's nothing to set. Do something like if(string != null) then setText else "toast"

Comment: Sorry, -1, op is asking about a simpler way to solve the problem. Introducing an mvp pattern here didn't add any value whatsoever.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך your solution just complicates it more. MVP or whichever would be the proper way of doing and he clearly didn't even know what an mvp pattern was so i think it's pretty well justified. I have no idea what you're on.

Comment: How can you expect op will know about mvp when he can't solve the trivial problem? I can't grasp the logic behind your statement.

Comment: And how does 3 line of code complicated the problem? Isn't mvp introduce more problem here? yagni.

Comment: He should learn to do it the right way not just hack together a solution. You're encouraging bad practices. @ישואוהבאותך

Comment: doing something unnecessary is bad practice. More codes introduce more bugs. And talking about the pattern, mvp is not always the right pattern. I'ts not the only way to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There are at least 2 ways to achieve that.

1. Using a return
2. Using a simple boolean flag.

.

**1. Using a return**
If your code is a method, you can use `return` statement something like this:

```
private void myCheckMethod(int value) {
  switch (value) {        
    case 1:
    case 2:
      replyOne.setText("string 1 & 2");
      break;
    case 3:
      replyOne.setText("string 3");
      break;
    default:
      Toast.makeText(this, "incorrect typing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return; // here the method will be terminated if checking is not valid.

    }

    makeContactMessage(replyOne, messagesLayout);
 }
```

**2. Using a simple boolean flag.**

Use a simple flag for calling the method. Here we using `isValid` variable:

```
boolean isValid = true; // always set checking as valid.

switch (integer) {        
  case 1:
  case 2:
    replyOne.setText("string 1 & 2");
    break;
  case 3:
    replyOne.setText("string 3");
    break;
  default:
    Toast.makeText(this, "incorrect typing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    isValid = false; // false, because we can't match anything.

}

if(isValid) {
  makeContactMessage(replyOne, messagesLayout);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really address his question in a suitable manner, just enforcing more bad practices